# Huge memory leak in NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks, appkit

I have a method that analyzes pixel data inside an NSBitmapImageRep that is built from a CGImageRef. Here is the relevant code:

```
CGImageRef ref;
// omitted code for initializing ref
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:ref];
uint32* bitmapPixels = (uint32*) [bitmapRep bitmapData];
// do stuff with bitmapPixels
[bitmapRep release];
CGImageRelease(ref);
```

I know I'm properly releasing the CGImageRef and NSBitmapImageRep, but the call to -bitmapData leaks about 2 MB each time it's called, and I don't know how to properly release it. Any ideas?

**Update:** I forgot to add one important point: memory is only leaked when there is a full screen application running. For regular usage, the memory is released just fine.

Comment: Quick look at the reference indicates that -bitMapData just returns a pointer to data within the bitmapRep object, and that therefore there should be no need to release it.

Can you turn on garbage collection and see what happens then? It might give you some clues.

Comment: @Tony Ken's solution seems to release the data once you're done with it.  Without a pool, it looks like the Mac just releases that data whenever it wants to.

Answer (score 4):

Are you doing this in a loop?  If so you might need to make an autorelease pool to make sure memory is cleaned up in a timely fashion.  See [autorelease pools](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

Comment: I had a similar problem to the one Nic asked about, and this solution was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I was looping through images, sometimes 200+ 5MB+ CIImages and NSBitmapImageReps at a time, and memory usage would peak around 2-3 GB (plus the system would get pretty slow). Adding an @autoreleasepool{} around the loop cut down peak memory usage to ~180 MB, and made the batch process take a few seconds instead of 1-2 min!

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap data should be owned by either the CGImage or the NSBitmapImageRep (or copied to an autoreleased behind-the-scenes NSData object by the latter). As such, whichever object owns (or copies) it should release it.

Are you seeing contrary results in heap/Instruments?